# how to compile clutter lib for wince 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl-es, windows-ce, clutter

I want to write a 3D application interface for wince 6.0.
my board support opengl es 1.1.
but i don't familiar with opengl|es.
i want to use clutter lib to write 3d appllcation application.

how to compile  clutter lib  with vs2008

please advise.

thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

It needs efforts to get these things done,there several dependencies needed,see the readme file in the lastest src archive.  However,we can get prebuild binary dependencies here:   ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/dependencies/  (32 bit)     ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/dependencies/ (64 bit)